# Failed to start mongod com.Could not find appropriate mongod in `/opt/mongodb/mms/mongodb-releases

Tags: mongodb

I am getting following error when I tried to activate a backup for mongo instance.
    I choosed local and copied all rpms to this folder /opt/mongodb/mms/mongodb-releases.

```
error:

Failed to start mongod
com.xgen.svc.brs.util.GenericMongoManager$MongodVersionException: Could not find appropriate mongod in `/opt/mongodb/mms/mongodb-releases/`, versions available to MMS: . Expecting version 3.4.4 or greater.
com.xgen.svc.brs.util.GenericMongoManager$Purpose.calculateBinaryPath(GenericMongoManager.java:166)
com.xgen.svc.brs.util.GenericMongoManager$Purpose.<init>(GenericMongoManager.java:125)
com.xgen.svc.brs.util.MongoManager$MongoDPurpose.<init>(MongoManager.java:331)
com.xgen.svc.brs.util.MongoManager$HeadPurpose.<init>(MongoManager.java:477)
com.xgen.svc.brs.job.ReplicaSetJob.startMongo(ReplicaSetJob.java:103)
com.xgen.svc.brs.job.ReplicaSetJob.startMongo(ReplicaSetJob.java:80)
com.xgen.svc.brs.job.IncrementalSyncJob.doWork(IncrementalSyncJob.java:82)
com.xgen.svc.brs.grid.Daemon.iterate(Daemon.java:116)
com.xgen.svc.brs.grid.Daemon.run(Daemon.java:305)
```

Comment: Can you run `ls -lart` on `/opt/mongodb/mms/mongodb-releases` directory?

Comment: here you go    -rw-r--r--  1 mongodb-mms mongodb-mms 100401773 Jun  3 23:08 mongodb-linux-x86_64-rhel70-3.4.4.tgz
drwxr-xr-x  3 mongodb-mms mongodb-mms      4096 Jun  3 23:12 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 mongodb-mms mongodb-mms        86 Jun  3 23:12 mongodb-linux-x86_64-rhel70-3.4.4
drwxr-xr-x 13 mongodb-mms mongodb-mms      4096 Jun  4 00:22 ..

Comment: this is solved after placing appropriate mongod version tar files.

Comment: Glad to know it solved the issue. Please add this as an answer. It will help others facing same issue. `-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb-mms mongodb-mms` from your comment says only root has that access